# I keep having this error 'Invalid Syntax near 'emppic' vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I've been working on saving an image to my sql database but to no avail. I keep having the same error of 'invalid syntax near @emppic'

I am new to vb.net and I have tried deleting the @emppic but I get the same error, just on a different line.

Here is the code:

```vbnet
    Try
    
        Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        PictureBox4.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        arrimage = mstream.GetBuffer()
        Dim filesize As UInt32
        filesize = mstream.Length
    
        mstream.Close()
        conn.ConnectionString = Str()
        conn.Open()
        Sql = "INSERT INTO  ADDEMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEEID,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,SEX, AGE, ADDRESS, BDAY, CONTACT,HEIGHT,WEIGHT,CITIZENSHIP,HIREDDATE, CIVILSTATUS,POSITION,USERNAME,PASSWORD,PAIDLEAVES,UNPAIDLEAVES,SSS,TIN,PHILHEALTH,PAGIBIG,EMPPIC) VALUES(@EMPLOYEEID, @FNAME, @MNAME, @LNAME,@SEX, @AGE, @ADDRESS, @BDAY, @CONTACT, @HEIGHT,@WEIGHT,@CITIZENSHIP,@HIREDDATE, @CIVILSTATUS,@POSITION,@USERNAME,@PASSWORD,@PAIDLEAVES,@UNPAIDLEAVES,@SSS,@TIN,@PHILHEALTH,@PAGIBIG, @EMPPIC"
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = Sql
    
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPLOYEEID", AE_EID.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", AE_FNAME.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MNAME", AE_MIDNAME.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", AE_LASTNAME.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEX", AE_SEX.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AGE", AE_AGE.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADDRESS", AE_ADDRESS.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BDAY", AE_BDAY.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTACT", AE_CONTACT.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HEIGHT", AE_HEIGHT.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WEIGHT", AE_WEIGHT.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CITIZENSHIP", AE_CITI.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HIREDDATE", AE_HIREDATE.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CIVILSTATUS", AE_CS.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POSITION", AE_POSITION.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", AE_USERNAME.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", AE_PASSWORD.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAIDLEAVES", AE_PL.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNPAIDLEAVES", AE_UPL.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSS", AE_SSS.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIN", AE_TIN.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PHILHEALTH", AE_PHIL.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAGIBIG", AE_PAGIBIG.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPPIC", arrimage)
    
        Dim r As Integer
        r = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If r > 0 Then
            MsgBox("successfully added")
        Else
            MsgBox("fail to save")
        End If
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        conn.Close()
    
    
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Missing parenthesis. -- Huge mistake: `arrimage = mstream.GetBuffer()`, you need to use `ToArray()`, not `GetBuffer()`. -- Better write `Dim arrimage  = New ImageConverter().ConvertTo(PictureBox4.Image, GetType(Byte()))` -- You should probably 
 convert to byte the original Bitmap.

Comment: Just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](https://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 1):

You want to close the VALUES( of the INSERT.
It must be ["INSERT() VALUES()"](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

```
Sql = "INSERT INTO  ADDEMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEEID,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,SEX, AGE, ADDRESS, BDAY, CONTACT,HEIGHT,WEIGHT,CITIZENSHIP,HIREDDATE, CIVILSTATUS,POSITION,USERNAME,PASSWORD,PAIDLEAVES,UNPAIDLEAVES,SSS,TIN,PHILHEALTH,PAGIBIG,EMPPIC) VALUES(@EMPLOYEEID, @FNAME, @MNAME, @LNAME,@SEX, @AGE, @ADDRESS, @BDAY, @CONTACT, @HEIGHT,@WEIGHT,@CITIZENSHIP,@HIREDDATE, @CIVILSTATUS,@POSITION,@USERNAME,@PASSWORD,@PAIDLEAVES,@UNPAIDLEAVES,@SSS,@TIN,@PHILHEALTH,@PAGIBIG, @EMPPIC)"
```